# css is not working in my blog page only other pages working properly in my django project

Tags: css, python-3.x, django, flexbox, django-templates

I am working on a django project. All css working well on my local server but when i am hosting on pythonanywhere.com then css of only /blog url not working properly. I can't able to find the error.
Please help me. You can visit my hosted website at http://sauravportfolio.pythonanywhere.com/blog/
and you can see my entire code at github https://github.com/saurav389/portfolio . you can see my all css code at portfolio/src/portfolio/static/css/ folder. and my bootstrap is not working in chrome browser too. Please do something for me.

Comment: The management of static files with django is a recurring issue.
However, most of your CSS requirements are taken into account. That means that the settings find the static files and that your html files finds the css.
 It should therefore mean that there is an issue within your html pages.
The impression I have is that the structures of your pages, the number of different templates you have in your blog directory for the templates leads you to call a obsolete html file.
Some cleaning up of the blog directory should help you to reestablish the correct connection.

Comment: why bootstrap is not working in chrome browser

Comment: Is it working in the other ones ?

Comment: Do you have your static files mapping set? Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles

Comment: ya i did static files mapping. Its working in all pages other than /blog page

Comment: what do you see in your browser dev tool? Do requested urls match what you expect?